# When using the convert function of the watson-developer-cloud Node.js library, how do I specify the mime type of the original document?

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using the watson-developer-cloud Node.js library to send HTML documents to Watson's Document Conversion service. The service tries to guess the mime/type for the documents that I'm sending but sometimes gets it wrong, so I want to specify the mime/type explicitly when making the call.  I know the document conversion service's REST API has a way to specify the document type, but **how do I specify the document type when using this call in the watson-developer-cloud library?**  The code below doesn't do it.

```
//"content" is the actual HTML
document_conversion.convert({file: {value: new Buffer(content), options: {}},
conversion_target: "ANSWER_UNITS",
type: "text/html"
}, function (err, response) {...
```

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104208/why-do-i-get-415-errors-from-watsons-document-conversion-service-on-certain-doc/37117066#37117066?

Comment: It looks like this is not currently possible with the node SDK, but it probably should bee. I'm going to see if I can add support today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file.options.contentType` trick works, but I just updated the library to make this "officially supported", with a bit friendlier syntax:

```
document_conversion.convert({
  file: new Buffer(content),
  content_type: "text/html",
  conversion_target: "ANSWER_UNITS"
}, function (err, response) {
  //...
});
```

This should work with `watson-developer-cloud` v1.7.0 and newer.

Comment: This does not seem to work any more.  Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396428/how-do-i-send-a-pdf-to-watsons-document-conversion-service-without-writing-it-t

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, for the benefit of future searchers.

Turns out that to do what I want to do, you have to put `contentType:"text/html"` in the ***options*** field, like this:

```
//"content" is the actual HTML
document_conversion.convert({file: {value: new Buffer(content), options: {contentType: "text/html"}},
conversion_target: "ANSWER_UNITS"
}, function (err, response) {...
```

Many thanks to **Joe Kozhaya** for setting me straight on this.